# Derivative of a scalar function with resepct to a Matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace

I need help with the following differentiation

$$
\text{trace}((aI+bXX^T)^{-1}(aI+XX^T))
$$

with respect to  $X$, where $a,b$ are some positive constants, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y=aI+bXX^T$ and $Z=aI+XX^T$. Then
\begin{align*}
d\operatorname{tr}(Y^{-1}Z)
&= \operatorname{tr}\left(dY^{-1}Z + Y^{-1}dZ\right)\\
&= \operatorname{tr}\left(-Y^{-1}dYY^{-1}Z + Y^{-1}dZ\right)\\
&= \operatorname{tr}\left(-b\,Y^{-1}(dXX^T+XdX^T)Y^{-1}Z
+ Y^{-1}(dXX^T+XdX^T)\right).
\end{align*}
Using the properties that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname(BA)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(M)=\operatorname{tr}(M^T)$, the last line in the above can be rewritten as $2\operatorname{tr}\left[dX^T\left(-b\,Y^{-1}ZY^{-1} + Y^{-1}\right)X\right]$. Hence the required derivative is
$$2\left(-b\,Y^{-1}ZY^{-1} + Y^{-1}\right)X$$
if the so-called "[denominator layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)" is used.

Comment: Great, thanks!!